# Connecting JanusGraph with springboot

Tags: gremlin, janusgraph

Connect JanusGraph using Springboot and perform some CRUD operations. Gremlin Server is started at 8182.
Tried with providing absolute path to read properties file.
is anything wrong with code or property file? need to configure anything in gremlin server yaml file?

**getting error
 `"java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.process.traversal.step.sideEffect.IoStep"`**
**`java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.process.traversal.step.filter.NoneStep`**

1. Dependencies:

```xml
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.janusgraph</groupId>
        <artifactId>janusgraph-core</artifactId>
        <version>0.5.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.janusgraph</groupId>
        <artifactId>janusgraph-berkeleyje</artifactId>
        <version>0.6.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.tinkerpop</groupId>
        <artifactId>gremlin-driver</artifactId>
        <version>3.2.9</version>
    </dependency>
```

2. Graph class

```java
@RestController
public class GraphT {

    @GetMapping("/test")
    String all() {
        Graph graph = JanusGraphFactory.open("conf/janusgraph-berkeleyje.properties");
        GraphTraversalSource g = graph.traversal();
        //Add one vertex
        g.addV("person").property("name", "bob").property("age", 27).iterate();
        //Confirm change
        g.tx().commit();
        //Try issuing a query to retrieve the value
        List<Map<String, Object>> result = g.V().valueMap("name", "age").toList();
        //The return value is[{name: ["bob"], age: [27]}]Should be returned
        for(Map<String, Object> vertex : result){
            //vertex is{name:["bob"], age: [27]}Should be
            ArrayList<String> names = (ArrayList<String>)vertex.get("name");  // ["bob"]Get
            ArrayList<Integer> ages = (ArrayList<Integer>)vertex.get("age");  // [27]Get
            String name = names.get(0);  //"bob"Get
            Integer age = ages.get(0);  //Get 27
            System.out.printf("name: %s, age: %s\n", name, age);
        }
        //Try issuing a query to retrieve the number of vertices
        Long count = g.V().count().next();
        System.out.printf("vertex count is %d\n", count);

        try {
            graph.close();
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            //deal with it
        }

        return " some result ";

    }

}
```

3. config file

```
  gremlin.graph=org.janusgraph.core.JanusGraphFactory
  storage.backend=berkeleyje
  storage.directory=../db/berkeley
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see two different problems in the setup you described:

## Incompatible library versions

You are mixing versions of JanusGraph and TinkerPop that are not compatible with another.
If you want to use version 0.6.1 of `janusgraph-berkeleyje`, then you should also use the same version for `janusgraph-core`. The newest version is 0.6.2 right now by the way so you may just want to use that version.
But more importantly: Versions 0.6.* of JanusGraph are compatible with versions 3.5.* of TinkerPop, but you are using version 3.2.9 of `gremlin-driver`.

The [JanusGraph release notes](https://docs.janusgraph.org/changelog/#version-062-release-date-may-31-2022) show which versions each JanusGraph release is compatible with. For 0.6.2 of JanusGraph, compatibility is tested with TinkerPop version 3.5.3, so I would use that version.

## JanusGraph Server vs Embedded JanusGraph

Apart from that, you say that you have started Gremlin Server, but then you are not connecting to that server in your Java code, but instead you are starting a local JanusGraph instance which directly uses Berkeley via `JanusGraphFactory.open()`. This means that your Java application will not use the started Gremlin Server at all.

You should decide whether you want to run JanusGraph as a server to which you can connect from various applications **or** using JanusGraph as a library which directly uses the storage backend.
You can read more about this difference in the section [*Deployment Scenarios* of the JanusGraph documentation](https://docs.janusgraph.org/operations/deployment/). *Embedded JanusGraph* is the scenario where JanusGraph is used as a library.

If you want to use JanusGraph Server (which is the Gremlin Server configured for JanusGraph) and connect to that remotely from your Java application, then the section [*Connecting from Java* of the documentation](https://docs.janusgraph.org/interactions/connecting/java/) explains how that can be done.